# Complex Analysis, Analytic Continuation

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Is there any function $ f$ analytic for $|z|<1$, such that

$f(1/2)=1/3$ and $f(\frac{1}{2n+1})=\frac{1}{2n+1}$ for $n=1, 2, 3, ...$?

I'm thinking analytic continuation, but I can't seem to get anywhere...

Comment: hint : $f(z) = z$ and the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)

Comment: The zeroes of a non-constant analytic function form a discrete set, but if $f$ were analytic, the zeroes of $f(z)-z$ would accumulate towards $0$. On the other hand, if $f(z)-z$ were $\equiv 0$, $f(1/2)\neq 1/3$.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, for pointing me in the correct direction!